# What do I need to implement to sync data between the two devices?(Mirroring a Core Data Store with CloudKit)

Tags: swift, core-data, synchronization, icloud, cloudkit

I'm mirroring a Core Data Store with CloudKit in my app.

Do I need configure my server for silent push notification for Core Data with mirroring iCloud?
And do I need this code below in AppDelegete.swift?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://donnywals.com")!) { data, response, error in
    print(data)
    completionHandler(.newData)
  }.resume()
}
```

I tested my app on a test flight and was able to sync between the two devices without having to prepare my own server.
(And I think it took about 20 seconds to sync.)

However, I see a lot articles about configuring servers for silent push(remote push?) notifications.
I’m confused about what is correct.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your app have to do with `URLSession` when using Cloud Kit?

Comment: I saw this article https://www.donnywals.com/updating-your-apps-with-silent-push-notifications/ and wanted to make sure if i need `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method or no

Comment: If you want "free" sync between Core Data and CloudKit, use `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer